# background-image: not working properly

Tags: html, css

I know people been asked similar questions but I couldn't find the right answer for my issue. So I am asking public to help with my issue. I have a img folder and i have a search.png image in it. Its a search icon that I am trying to use it for my youtube search API page. So the problem that I am having is when I put the search.png to my background: url(../img/search.png) its not showing up at all, instead its empty square box. I will attach my code below. Please dont dislike my issue question I really need an answer.

```css
*{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

body{
 font-family:"Segoue",sans-serif;
 line-height:2em;
 color:#000000;
 background:#e1e1e1 url(../img/red.jpg) fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 /*background-position: cover;*/
 background-size: cover;
 font-size:13px;
}

a{
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
}

#container{
 /*height: 100px;*/
 width:740px;
 background:#f4f4f4;
 opacity: 0.9;
 margin:auto;
 margin-top: 300px;
 /*border: 2px solid black;*/
}

.clearfix{
 clear:both;
}

header{
 padding:30px 20px;
 background:#f4f4f4;
}

header h1{
 color:#001373;
 margin-bottom:5px;
}

header span{
 color:#000000;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-radius: 5%;
 background-color: #007EFF;
 padding: 8px;
}

section{
 padding:30px 20px 20px 20px;
}

footer{
 padding:20px;
 background:#f4f4f4;
 text-align:center;
}

#search{
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.fieldcontainer{
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#search-btn{
 position: absolute;
 right: 360px;
 top: 5px;
 height: 32px;
 width: 32px;
 border: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 zoom: 1;
 filter: alpha(opacity=65);
 opacity: 0.65;
 background-image: transparent url(../img/search.png) top-left no-repeat;
}

#search-btn:hover{
 filter: alpha(opacity=90);
 opacity: 0.9;
}

.search-field{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: block;
 width: 45%;
 padding: 7px 17px;
 padding-right: 43px;
 background-color: #BBB3F7;
 color: #75026C;
 font-weight: bolder; 
 border-radius: 1px solid black;
 font-size: 1.6em;
 border-color: #00B5ED;
 border-radius: 1px;
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 cursor: default;

}
```

```html
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="container">
   <header>
    <h1>Search<span>Vidz</span></h1>
    <p>Search all Youtube videos</p>
   </header>
   <section>
    <form id="search-form" name="search-form" onsubmit="return search()">
     <div class="fieldcontainer">
      <input type="search" id="query" class="search-field" placeholder="Search YouTube...">
      <input type="submit" name="search-btn" id="search-btn" value="">
     </div>
    </form>
    
    <ul id="results"></ul>
    <div id="buttons"></div>
   </section>
   <footer>
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2014, All Rights Reserved</p>
   </footer>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the path of the CSS file?, or are you adding styles directly on the HTML file?

Comment: No its in the css folder and im getting out of folder first by adding two ..

Comment: just to have things clear, CSS is into css folder, which is sister folder of img, right?

Comment: My style.css is inside the css folder and my search.png is is in the img folder

Comment: but both folders, img and css are siblings?, are those at the same hierarchy level?

Comment: Yeah they are in the same folder called My project/ js folder, css folder, img folder and index.html

Comment: Take a look to my response below...

Comment: No bro its not working

Comment: Post the exact folder path to the image file and the CSS file, as that matters very much in the way you define the path in your CSS rule

Answer (score 2):

check the image file extension!

Comment: Its not extension problem

Comment: when I open console I found this issue `GET http://stacksnippets.net/img/search.png 404 (Not Found)` just to make sure that you are putting the extension in a right way, put the image file beside the page file and use this extension `url(search.png)`

Comment: @AlaaMh Of course you do, the image path is local to his server, not to stacknippets

Comment: It says on my console "invalid property value" for the background: url(search.png) –

Comment: i figured out thanks it was a top-left that dash in between top left

Answer (score 0):

You write "search.jpg" in your code. Change to "search.png"

Comment: Its search.png on my actual code idont know how I submitted as jpg lol

Comment: can u share your actual page? Is it on the online server?

Comment: As your image resource isn't included in the snippet. It's difficult to understand. Can you send the full project(zip) ?

Comment: i got it it was a dash problem in between top-left

Answer (score 0):

The issue is syntax, you have `background-image: transparent url(../img/search.png) top-left no-repeat;`, but all properties should be assigned to the shorthand `background:`, `background-image` expects only the image (url). Additionally, the position should not be "top-left" but "top left" (two words)

Correct version of that line should be:

```
    background: transparent url(../img/search.png) top left no-repeat;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I know I stied both background: and background-image. No luck

Comment: If you want to use background-image, you'll need several lines: `background-color: transparent; background-image: url(../img/search.png); background-position:  top left; background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Comment: You can use the browser inspect tools, focus on the `#search-btn` element, and hover on the image URL, if the browser says that could not find image, is a path issue; otherwise there are chances to be syntax or CSS itself, for instance, I won't recommend having the button positioned using `right: 360px`, because `.fieldcontainer` and `.searchfield` both have percentage width, I'd recommend use a shorter value, instead of `right: 360px`, using `left: 5px`, so to speak.

Comment: It says on my console "invalid property value" for the background: url(search.png)

Comment: OMG finally i figured out its crazy man the problem was " - " in between top-left. there is not supposed to be a dash in between.

Comment: I told you in my previous comment, I'll appreciate if you award me the answer